# C# How to check if event handler is finished

Tags: c#, silverlight, event-handling

Is there an elegant way of checking to see if an event had finished or not? My only options appears to create another event handler that gets called when my first event is finished.

Comment: Event handlers are called synchronously so it's "finished" when the code path returns to the caller.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth What do you mean?! I'm not familiar with event handlers in c# , but isn't the essence of an event handler, that the calling action causing the event is completed first, and the triggered action is run after (or in a separate thread)

Comment: Please state some simple code explaining your question, TruthOf42

Comment: @nl-x A simple demo application would prove this to you. I think you *can* call them asynchronously, but most of the time you don't.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth : If I were to have a form with a button that fills a label, and then stalls `while (1) {}` ... I would never see that label be filled. Because the stalling holds off the events needed to fill the label (invalidate, etc). That would at least prove that the triggered events are run AFTER the block causing the event finish.

Comment: @nl-x I fail to see what you are trying to say with that statement. It might be that you are getting confused with events and windows messages, which are queued up until the UI thread can pump the message queue to perform actions such as repainting controls. Also `while (1) {}` won't actually compile because `1` doesn't evaluate to a `bool`.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth well, ... I was just thinking in the sense of built-in events such as having a button telling a form that a label needs to be changed. The button changes property label.Text , and that will trigger an event actually changing my screen. I can prove that the changing-the-screen doesn't happen until the complete button_click event is finished by putting a `while (1) {}` in my button_click. ... Thus the button_click never finishes. And indeed my screen never updates. (The application freezes, unless I go multi-threaded.)

Comment: @nl-x That's backwards. What happens is the setting of the `label.Text` property will post a message to the UI message queue, then the event returns to your calling code. Because you are blocking the UI thread with a loop, the UI thread cannot pump the message queue to process the paint message that says "need to repaint because `Text` was changed". Your code is proving that the code runs on the same thread, not that the event-calling method needs to complete before the event code is run. Think of calling an event like a list of methods - default is synchronous calling.

Comment: @nl-x My experience is with `WinForms` specifically, but WPF has a message pump underneath it, not entirely certain about Silverlight but I'd cast an educated guess it's similar.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Thanks. This is good to know. So an event is fired/triggered/handled synchronously and directly before the caller returns. Kind of like setter/getter ?

Comment: @nl-x Yes, but more like a straight method calls. Events are just collections of method pointers (delegates). In C#, property getter/setters are actually compiled into methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is no any multithreading envolved in calling chain, just call event handler funciton at the end of the first one:

```
public void HandlingEvent( ...) {

   //do some stuff 


   RaiseAnotherEventHandler();

}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, but I was hoping there was some easier way than having to create a new event handler. oh well

Answer (score 0):

Event handlers are nothing but multicast delegates with return type as VOID. Internally it implements the Observer pattern and the message is broadcasted to all the subscribers when the event is invoked/raised by the event notifier. By principle, the event notifier does not worry about what happens at the subscribers end, but, if there are any exceptions occurred at the subscriber and, and not handled, then the exception is re-thrown to the notifier. So if you enclose your event invoking/raising code within a try/catch block, and if your event raising/invoking code executes without any exceptions, then it means that all the event handlers/subscribers are executed and the event execution is finished.